# Button to change color on focus using tab key and back to original color on pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I reach my button using tab key and after that when it does a focus, I want it to change color so that it shows that you have reached the button and, when you press the enter key, it should change its color back to original.

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
            <input id=" vehicles" class="button calculator large top-right-border transition" type="submit" name="submit"   />
        </div>
```

and CSS is

```
#vehicles:hover{
     background: red;
}
#vehicles:focus{
     background: red;
}
#vehicles{
     background: green;
}
```

On pressing enter I want my color to go back to green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using :active won't revert it back to green for good. You will probably need to use JavaScript to unfocus the button.

```
<input id="vehicles" type="submit" onkeypress="if (event.which === 13) this.blur()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between the opening parenthesis and `vehicles` in your `id` assignment in the `input` element, so your CSS styling isn't applying to it. It should be

```
<input id="vehicles".../>
```

rather than

```
<input id=" vehicles".../>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/k8gsx7rg/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :active instead of :focus. It will give you your required solution

```
<input id="vehicles" class="button calculator large top-right-border transition" type="submit" name="submit"   />


#vehicles:hover{
     background: red;
}
#vehicles:active{
     background: red;
}
#vehicles{
     background: green;
}
```

Find the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xaz9gvqf/)

Its will work for you.
Use jQuery for focus-defocus. for more please go through

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: with active it does not change color on focus......when I reach the button using the tab key

Comment: You can use jQuery for focus out as css de-focus will not work for you. Please find more with the answer of Arbitrator http://www.codingforums.com/html-css/107076-css-focus-defocus-does-not-work.html

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps,

```
 <html><body>

<input type="submit" 
       id="vehicles" 
       style="background-color:red;" 
       onfocus ="change_color()"/>

    <script>
        function change_color()
        {
            document.getElementById("vehicles").style.backgroundColor="Blue";
        }
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>`
```